# Error invoking Class in Java

Tags: java, class

Unable to invoke the class, although i defined it. I tried with many methods.

**Error:**

```
error: cannot find symbol 
StopWord d= new StopWord();//test for StopWord 
^ 
symbol: class StopWord
```

**Code:**

This is my main file

```
public  static void main(String[]args)throws Exception {
    StopWord dis= new StopWord();
    System.out.println("whencesoever is in Hahtable :" +
            dis.isStopWord("whencesoever"));
}
```

And my file that contains Class StopWord is

```
public class StopWord {
   public static boolean isStopWord(String s) {
    //statements
   }
}
```

Regards!!!

Comment: you need a return statement in isStopWord to compile: `return true;` will do.

Comment: This is my exact error  error: cannot find symbol
        StopWord d= new StopWord();//test for StopWord
        ^
        symbol:   class StopWord.... Sorry Im new to java may i know what is sb??

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote the question, the code might be low quality as OP is an unexperienced programmer, but the question itself is clearly related to programming and the user needs some leads to resolve the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Did you import the `StopWord` class ?

Side note:

if `isStopWord` is static, you should call it like this:

```
    StopWord.isStopWord("whencesoever"));
```

if you want to call `dis.isStopWord("whencesoever"))` do not mark it `static`, ie

```
public boolean isStopWord(String s)
```

Comment: Ofcourse I have return statement... bt i haven't mentioned here!!! Still getting the same error... And should i import stopword in my main file???

Comment: you should import `StopWord` in the file where you have the main method.

Comment: But i use same package for both the file... Is there need to import my class into main file

Comment: do you have an error at compile time or at run time? also can you give the exact line which give the error?

Comment: My error falls at compile time... I use `package tf_idf;` in both the file.. When i compile my main file it throws an `error: cannot find symbol`

Answer (score -1):

This may help

```
 public Class Test{
        public  static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException sb;

            StopWord dis= new StopWord();
            System.out.println("whencesoever is in Hahtable :" +
                    dis.isStopWord("whencesoever"));
        }
    }
```

There is no return statement.

```
public class StopWord{
   public static boolean isStopWord(String s){
           return true;
      }
  }
```

#### static  is not required.

```
 public class StopWord{
       public boolean isStopWord(String s){
               return true;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Why change the method's signature?

Comment: because program is expecting String and method return type is boolean . This is wrong.

Comment: "program is expecting String" => No, it isn't.

Comment: you can return a boolean and it will print it just fine

Comment: Yes correct. My mistake. Thank u.Just a Return is missing.